# Custom style is interfering with platform dialogs

Tags: android, android-theme

I've created a custom theme for my app, and it looks great! However, I've noticed that some default platform dialogs, such as the context menu when long-pressing an `EditText` doesn't show correctly.

On the left, a context menu through my app. On the right, a standard context menu through a platform app.

[image: My app's theme]
[image: System default theme]

Here's my `style.xml`:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
        <!-- ... various app styles ... -->
        <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/DialogHolo</item>
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogHolo</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogHolo" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:fullDark">@drawable/bg_dialog_full</item>
        <item name="android:topDark">@drawable/bg_dialog_top</item>
        <item name="android:centerDark">@drawable/bg_dialog_middle</item>
        <item name="android:bottomDark">@drawable/bg_dialog_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:fullBright">@drawable/bg_dialog_full</item>
        <item name="android:centerBright">@drawable/bg_dialog_middle</item>
        <item name="android:bottomBright">@drawable/bg_dialog_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:bottomMedium">@drawable/bg_dialog_bottom</item>
        <item name="android:centerMedium">@drawable/bg_dialog_middle</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffe6e7e8</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Is it possible to either have these dialogs use the default style or get the text to appear in the desired text color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found an elegant solution for this, and instead simply provided a theme defined separately in my `style.xml` when displaying a custom dialog.